# Is it possible to split the main 25%/50%/25% vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three divs and I want them to be aligned vertically (like 3 columns) and set the size to 25% for both left and right, and 50% for the middle one.
Also, I want them to be infinite and scrollable and each one adapt his size based on others columns.

Comment: Isn't 25% of infinity infinite?

Comment: flexbox would be one option.

Comment: @Teemu mind blown. OP - Care to share your code?

Comment: @Teemu, question isn't well explained but you can understand that "the main" mean `window` or `screen`

Comment: @Ognyan, I updated your question because of the unclear flag, can you be sure this is what you want ? And If yes, don't forget to accept an answer to close your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy with Flex box. 
Check [this awesome guide here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
/* Normalize */
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Flex power */
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container > * {
  width: 100%; /* Not mandatory, but to be sure */
}
.flex-25 {
  height: 25%;
  background: red;
}
.flex-50 {
  height: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-25">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-50">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-25">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT

```css
/* Normalize */
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2em;
}

/* Flex power */
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.flex-25 {
  width: 25%;
  background: #333;
  color: #EEE;
}
.flex-50 {
  width: 50%;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-25">
    <p>Not much here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-50">
    <p>To infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>and infinity<br/>..<br/>..<br/>..<br/>..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-25">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to split the screen vertically not horizontally.

Comment: Okay I understand.. I updated my answer to get 3 infinite columns of 25/50/25

Answer (score 3):

You have to use display grid and make usage of 3 rows, you do it like this.

I just see you asked for infinite height or something like that so yes grid is the way to go when you use vh (viewport height), the same with vw (viewport width)

```css
    .main{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 25vh 50vh 25vh;
     grid-template-areas: 'div1''div2''div3';
    }

    .div1{
     background-color:red;
  
     grid-area: div1;
    }

    .div2{
      background-color:green;
     grid-area: div2;
    }

    .div3{
      background-color:blue;
     grid-area: div3;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div1">
     First row
  </div>
   <div class="div2">
     Second row
  </div>
    <div class="div3">
     Third row
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your output, but I want to split the screen vertically not horizontally.

Comment: aren't rows vertically? Maybe if I understand it wrong you can replace grid-template-rows with  grid-template-columns if its that what you mean :)

Comment: By saying "vertically" he probably want to say "like (vertical) columns". Also `grid-template` support on browser is good (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) but flexbox is better (https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily using flexbox, since flexbox is responsive. Create a `div` that acts as a container and set it to `display: flex;`. Flexbox by default goes in the direction you want, so just create a class for the first and third divs with `width: 25%;` and a class for the second div with `width: 50%;`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.sm {
    width: 25%;
    background: orange;
}
.lg {
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="sm">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
   <div class="lg"></div>
   <div class="sm"></div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You're code insn't handling the "infinite" request, try to put lots of lines on one column and it's broken. switch `height:100%;` to `min-height:100%` and add `align-items: stretch;` to container